# Eliminating temp var use when accessing a multidimensional array element

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, point, indices

Is there a way to address array object's field with its coordinates in one line?

I have this array: `Tile[,] Tiles`. Whenever I need to change one of the tiles and I know the indices beforehand, I just do it like this: `Tiles[1, 2] = new Tile(args);`.

But when I have to calculate them, it looks like this:

```
Point p = GetTargetTileIndices(args);
Tiles[p.X, p.Y].someField = 127;
```

Storing tile's indices each time in a temp variable gets confusing and sometimes hard to read. Is there a way to get the indices as `Point` or something else and work with target array element in one line?

---

**UPD:** It is now clear to me that doing…

```
var tile = GetTile(point);
tile.field = value;
```

…does not change the tile in the array, but…

```
GetTile(point).field = value;
```

…does!

Comment: @DonRoby, it appears to be C#.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a `Dictionary<Point, Tile>` or `Dictionary<{type of args}, Tile>`?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud There are about 20 million tile objects per map, and I'm not sure Dictionary of any kind is faster than Array, though I haven't checked yet.

Comment: @user1306322, it's not about faster. Your question was about readability.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I guess when talking about a tile-based game, some sacrifices must be made :)

Comment: @user1306322, what? I think you've switched gears. What are you saying when you say `some sacrifices must be made`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `GetTargetTile` helper method... just like your `GetTargetTileIndices` but instead of a `Point` it returns the actual `Tile`

Comment: I already have a `GetTile(Point)` and `GetTile(int, int)`, and they do exactly what they are called, but what I'm trying to do it set some value of a tile at runtime calculated address and I can't figure out how to make a `SetTilesFieldValue(Point, Field, Value)` method.

Comment: is *Field* variable or static?  I'd assume it is some field you don't know at design time.

Comment: I'm not really sure what problem you are trying to solve... if you are only setting one field, do GetTile(args).Field=Value;  otherwise, if you are doing multiple things with the tile, call GetTile and store the result in a local variable that you can party on.  This is what local variables are for :)

Comment: I was sure that when I do `GetTile(args).Field=Value;` it will only change local copy of the tile, but then everything was ok because in this case I don't assign the tile to a local variable at all. Problem was I usually stored tiles in local vars, which after changing I had to put back to the array explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your own method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(this T[,] array, Point point)
    {
        return array[point.X, point.Y];
    }

    public static void SetValue<T>(this T[,] array, Point point, T value)
    {
        array[point.X, point.Y] = value;
    }
}
```

Note that here if `Tiles` is a value type (struct) then you'll get back a copy from this method, so modifying one of it's properties will be modifying a copy and won't be helpful.

Using this method your code simply becomes:

```
Tiles.GetValue(GetTileIndices()).byte = 8;
```